# incompatibility between int and float (regarding which criteria)

Tags: c++, floating-point, integer, numbers

I was reading about the strict Aliasing and stopped on citation saying :

> An object shall have its stored value accessed only by an lvalue
> expression that has one of the following types:
>
> - a type compatible with the effective type of the object.

at the first place I was thinking that int and float are compatible regarding theire size as size of int is equal to 4 bytes which is the same for thz size of float.

So I am wondering, int and float are incompatible regarding of what ?

Thank you and sorry of my question is little stupid :)

Edit : added code example

```
#include <stdio.h> 

void f(void) {
  if (sizeof(int) == sizeof(float)) {
    float f = 0.0f;
    int *ip = (int *)&f;
    (*ip)++;
    printf("float is %f\n", f);
  }
}
```

Comment: Where did you find this quote? It should have been accompanied by an explanation of "compatible" in this context (which looks like [the context](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Type_aliasing) in which cppreference.com uses the term "similar").

Comment: They are incompatible regarding their effective type. What's the mystery?

Comment: @user207421 do u mean by effective type , the stored type ?

Comment: @JaMiT : I added an example which said that it is not a compliant and is UB as we increment the float pointer by integer one.

Comment: There is more to "compatibility"  (i.e. the ability to use a pointer cast and treat something of type `float` as if it is a `int`, or vice versa) than the sizes of `float` and `int`.     Even when they are the same size, the two types can represent different sets of values (e.g. a `float` cannot represent all the integral values that an `int` can, and `int` cannot represent non-integral values that a `float` can).     In any event, the statement `(*ip)++` has undefined behaviour, since `ip` does not actually point at an `int`.

Comment: Even though they have the same size, the internal format of an `int` and a `float` are very incompatible.

Comment: @Blood-HaZaRd Sorry, I fail to see how that example relates to my question. Am I supposed to search for that example across the web and in every book, journal, magazine, etc. ever written to guess which resource you are quoting?

Comment: The text you quote is from the C standard (C 2018 6.5 7) and is not applicable to C++. C++ uses different terminology and techniques for specifying what accesses are defined. The corresponding passage in C++ 2017 draft N4659 is 6.10 8: “If a program attempts to access the stored value of an object through a glvalue of other than one of the following types the behavior is undefined: … — a type similar (as defined in 7.5) to the dynamic type of the object,…” (that is one sample item from the list, see the original for the full list).

Comment: @Eric if i m not mistaken the same prarag that i copied is also applied in c11 standard and the glvalue was added in C14 or later. Not sure about it

Answer (score 1):

"I was thinking that int and float are compatible regarding theire size as size of int is equal to 4 bytes which is the same for thz size of float." does **not** meet the "a type compatible with the effective type of the object."

> So I am wondering, int and float are incompatible regarding of what ?

There are not certainly the same size.  Even if the same size, the types may differ in alignment needs.  Addresses (uncommonly) of `int` object  may even differ is size from addresses of `float`.  `int *ip = (int *)&f;` may result in undefined behavior.

To best re-interpret integer data as floating point data first deserves a clear use case.